# How to append column side by side in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
TEST_NUM    SITE_NUM    RESULT  TEST_FLG    TEST_TXT    UNITS   LO_LIMIT    HI_LIMIT
0   100        0    -0.4284 P   Continuity_PPMU XSCI    V             -1    -0.3
1   100        1    -0.4274 P   Continuity_PPMU XSCI    V             -1    -0.3
2   100        2    -0.4276 P   Continuity_PPMU XSCI    V             -1    -0.3
3   100        3    -0.4289 P   Continuity_PPMU XSCI    V             -1    -0.3
4   101        0    -0.4569 P   Continuity_PPMU XSCO    V             -1    -0.3
```

The **`TEST_TXT`** has 53 unique values.

I want my dataframe to be like this

```
LDO_Discharge V12  | Continuity_PPMU XSCI | Continuity_PPMU XSCO |Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0 |Continuity_PPMU ADBUS1 ....
 1.04              |3.343                                      |1.91    | 2.1 | 3.1
```

Basically, all values of `RESULT` column of different `TEST_TXT` side by side, as a column.
But the trick here is, `LDO_Discharge V12` has 5512 values, `Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0` has 5528 values. They need to be side-by-side on the basic of `SITE_NUM`.

So, First the row of `LDO_Discharge V12` with SITE_NUM = 0, should have First row of `Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0` with SITE_NUM = 0 and so on. They should joined such that they have same SITE_NUM.

I would have done this easily if the SITE_NUM was unique or their count were equivalent, but it is not so (5512 for 'LDO_Discharge V12' vs 5528 for 'Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0' or other value).

I want to ask how to combine such that "`Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0`" `SITE_NUM` goes with `LDO_Discharge V12`'s `SITE_NUM` in the order.

And if there are no values for a particular set(say SITE_NUM = 3 is missing for "`Continuity_PPMU XSCI`", it is possible as counts are different for different "`TEST_TXT`"s) , it should leave a `NULL` there.

It was hard to explain like this. Please let me know if some more clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understood what your expected output is supposed to be like, so it might help if you could clarify that. However, from what I gathered, you should take a look at some `pandas` functions. Therefore:

Check out `axis = 1` argument of [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), which let's you concatenate in the direction of the rows.

```py
df = pd.concat(iterator, axis = 1) # returns a DataFrame
```

But maybe you want to check out [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and then [`pd.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and after grouping you should take a look at [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), which would be something like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
gdf = df.groupby(by = columns_to_group).agg({column_agg: function_agg, ...}) # returns DataFrame after `agg`
```

Comment: My apologies for not being able to express. Let me rephrase it. The df(it has size 29200) has a column called "TEST_TXT" which has overall 53 unique "TEST_TXT" so obviously some of them repeats. "LDO_Discharge V12" is one such value and has a count 5512. Similarly "Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0" has a count of 5528, so does "Continuity_PPMU ADBUS1" and so on. I want to have a datafrmae with headers = unique(TEST_TXT) from original df. Like "LDO_Discharge V12", "Continutiy ADBUS0" etc. So total 53 columns in new df with 5512 rows(according to LDO_Discharge). Part(1)

Comment: Part(2) - But, to be able to append values from these, there should be some ordering right ? So here comes SITE_NUM. One ideal set has 4 SITE_NUMS {0,1,2,3} and this is for each TEST_TXT. So, when I do like this df.loc[df["TEST_TXT"] == "LDO_Discharge V12"]], I get all rows with "LDO_Discharge V12", and when I do df.loc[df["TEST_TXT"] == "Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0"]], I get all rows with "Continuity ADBUS0". So when make a new df with these values side by side. First "LDO_Discharge V12" value with site 0 should go with first "ADBUS 0" value with site 0 and so on.

Comment: part(3) - But since the counts of both the features are different. 5512 of "LDO discharge" vs 5528 of "ADBUS 0", it is possible that count SITE_NUM = 0 in LDO discharge is different than that of "ADBUS 0". So in that case, we need to fill NULL where it is missed. SITE_NUM keeps on repeating value. For each "TEST_TXT" it ideal goes from {0,1,2,3} then repeats {0,1,2,3} and so on. But in some cases a set might only have {0,1,2} or even SITE_NUM {0} and so on.

Comment: Please let me know if this made something clear. Also, I will check your solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay. When you do `df[df.columns == value]` you select where `df.columns == value`, as you stated. `groupby` does the same thing, but for an entire column. Therefore, for a start, you just need to `groupby` your `TEST_TXT` column. Using `groupby` you will be able to use a method called `get_groups` which will return a `pd.DataFrame` with each of the possible groups - then you can visualize the groupings.

Comment: Furthermore, to fill in the NULLS, you should use `pd.DataFrame.fillna` which finds and fills them with some value: beware that there are many ways to fill in 'the blanks' and there are good and bad ways to do it, depends on what you might be trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you'd like, reading [`multiindex indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) might help you get a feel of how to manipulate your data.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about sorting my data, because after you get the `pd.DataFrame` the way you wanted, you can just `pd.DataFrame.sort_values` by the desired columns, so no worries.